# How can i format Double value comma separtely

Tags: java

I am currently working on salary disbursement module in Spring MVC, in application level, i store my salary data in double type, `eg double amount=32690597`

i want to format it like 32,690,597, so it become more readable.

Suggest me the best solution for this thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%1$,.0f", amount));
```

**OR**

```
String formatAmount = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###,###").format(amount);
```

**OR - Java 8**

```
NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
String formatAmount = numberFormatter.format(amount);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much specially for java 8

Answer (score 2):

Use `DecimalFormat` for this problem.

```
double amount = 32690597;
//create pattern for decimal format
String pattern = "###,###";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);

//change dot with comma
String formattedNumber = decimalFormat.format(amount).replace(".",",");
```

In detail Decimal Formatter keys ;

```
0   A digit - always displayed, even if number has less digits (then 0 is displayed)
#   A digit, leading zeroes are omitted.
.   Marks decimal separator
,   Marks grouping separator (e.g. thousand separator)
E   Marks separation of mantissa and exponent for exponential formats.
;   Separates formats
-   Marks the negative number prefix
%   Multiplies by 100 and shows number as percentage
?   Multiplies by 1000 and shows number as per mille
¤   Currency sign - replaced by the currency sign for the Locale. Also makes formatting use the monetary decimal separator instead of normal decimal separator. ¤¤ makes formatting use international monetary symbols.
X   Marks a character to be used in number prefix or suffix
'   Marks a quote around special characters in prefix or suffix of formatted number.
```

Some Examples with this ;

```
Pattern      Number        Formatted String
###.###      123.456       123.456
###.#        123.456       123.5
###,###.##   123456.789    123,456.79
000.###      9.95          009.95
##0.###      0.95          0.95
```

Comment: wow, very nice explanation, however my problem is fixed now, but still I vote up for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
static String formatDouble(double input){
    String inputString = new String(Double.toString(input));
    char[] array= inputString.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("");
    for(int i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        str.insert(0, array[i]);
            if(i % 3 == 0 && i != 0){
            str.insert(0, ",");
            }
        }
    return str.toString();
    }
```

Hope this helps

Better use String.format

Comment: Thanks so much dear,it seems the traditional and manual way to achieve the same, it literally improves the learning capability of a beginner and yeah congrats to you to be part of code of conduct.All the best

Comment: Thank you, I updated the code as it was relying on certain aspects of the compiler. The updated example above should work every where.